# ipython --pylab on cygwin: TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: matplotlib, cygwin, tkinter, ipython

I recently installed ipython as per instructions here: http://ardiyu07.blogspot.com/2012/04/ipython-012-installation-in-cygwin.html.

When I run `'ipython --pylab'` I get the error message below. I have googled around and have found postings about this error but in different context. Mine occurs when I launch ipython with the --pylab argument. I know this has something to do with the matplotlib gui interaction but not sure what exactly. I appreciate the guidance.

```
$ ipython --pylab
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

Welcome to pylab, a matplotlib-based Python environment [backend: TkAgg].
For more information, type 'help(pylab)'.
[TerminalIPythonApp] GUI event loop or pylab initialization failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_pylab(self, gui, import_all)
   2780         # Now we must activate the gui pylab wants to use, and fix %run to take
   2781         # plot updates into account
-> 2782         self.enable_gui(gui)
   2783         self.magics_manager.registry['ExecutionMagics'].default_runner = \
   2784         mpl_runner(self.safe_execfile)

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/inputhook.pyc in enable_gui(gui, app)
    526         e = "Invalid GUI request %r, valid ones are:%s" % (gui, guis.keys())
    527         raise ValueError(e)
--> 528     return gui_hook(app)
    529

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/inputhook.pyc in enable_tk(self, app)
    322         if app is None:
    323             import Tkinter
--> 324             app = Tkinter.Tk()
    325             app.withdraw()
    326             self._apps[GUI_TK] = app

/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.pyc in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   1683                 baseName = baseName + ext
   1684         interactive = 0
-> 1685         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   1686         if useTk:
   1687             self._loadtk()

TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: I don't know if tkinter is compatible with cygwin. Do you need to use cygwin? You can install IPython & matplotlib on Windows without needing cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have other dependencies on cygwin which is why I would like to remain consistent with the run time environment. The website with the installation instructions I quote above seems to indicate that ipython and matplotlib should work with cygwin since the instructions are for cygwin.

Comment: It appears that you now need to install X11 in Cygwin for tkinter - the linked post might have been using an older version. http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-02/msg00115.html

Comment: this is the same as X/Cygwin (http://x.cygwin.com/)? I just installed and I get the same error. :(

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to hope that someone who knows more about Cygwin can help with that, then.

Comment: Okay thanks Thomas. I appreciated your help! Hopefully, I can figure this out.

Comment: can this help?
http://jessresearch.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-display-name-and-no-display.html

Answer (score 1):

Type `startxwin` into the cygwin terminal ( you will need the X11 libraries available from the cygwin setup.exe ) You can then run `ipython --pylab` from the new terminal window and a command like `plot(range(10))` which will open a new window but you will need to also call `plt.draw()` for the plot to appear unlike in native pylab, the control over windows for the plots in cygwin is also poor compared to native pylab.

I didn't need to edit any setup files in this process, you may need to 'pip uninstall matplotlib' and reinstall until you have the required libraries installed via the cygwin setup.exe ( tkinter and I believe X11-devel libraries are required ).

Get setuptools via ez_setup.py

```
wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
python ez_setup.py
easy_install pip 
pip install numpy 
pip install ipython
pip install matplotlib
```